# trelloApp with Oauth as a library does not seem to work

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script, trello

I am trying to make a trelloApp library for Google Apps Script which works fine when I run it as the owner of the script. Now when adding it as a library to a script of another user I always get an error message about using the wrong token.

This would be the library **MXATH_jOrClwhJxK58e3b7OPNgVSik-PP**

To test would be

```
var API_KEY = "Your Api Key";  //https://trello.com/1/appKey/generate


function test() {
   var app = trelloApp.openById(API_KEY)

   var organizations = app.getMyOrganizations();

   for (var i = 0; i < organizations.length; i++) {
     var organization = organizations[i];
     Logger.log(organization.getId()+ ' ' + organization.getDisplayName())
   }
}
```

[This would be the library in itselve](https://script.google.com/d/1XYij_YrSsucuQawEbv3zhhu1l3guvI6-VigPIgm-rOBbTG-wB6g8XVgT/edit?usp=sharing)  (I removed the script properties with the keys)

And the error I am getting is: ***Response truncated by the server: expired token (use the option muteHttpExceptions to view the complete repsonse completa) (line 50, archieve "")***

The [oauth1 depreceation](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1) for Google apps Script does not seem to matter as it works fine with my own user.

Comment: Did you use the muteHttpExceptions to fetch the complete response of what the error is?

Comment: Yep! The url gives unexpexted token. UrlFetchApp.fetch([https://api.trello.com/1/members/me/organizations?key=469eaa65f40b7b2849302381be9&token=e64f42523631a677cd135f6d36340ce809090900eb10d9565d1a283fad08c7c2dc, {method=GET, muteHttpExceptions=true, oAuthUseToken=always}]) [0.672 seconds]
[15-08-01 10:36:05:327 BRT] HTTPResponse.getContentText() [0.004 seconds]
[15-08-01 10:36:05:330 BRT] Execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: i (line 20, file "APP", project "trelloApp") [0.79 seconds total runtime

Comment: which one is Line 20?

Comment: Using the oauth1 library the use UrlFetchApp.fetch is wrong and should be should service.fetch. Still though I was unable to put the entire Oauth flow in a library. There seems to be a mismatch between the authorizer and the script executer...

Comment: I'm having a go at a GAS Trello library myself, is the link to the latest copy of your library? Thanks, Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Nice looking library - just what I was looking for after much head-scratching about the Trello API!

I took [a copy](https://script.google.com/d/1vYHdA7pNNgAFv4feuzRfr8brnYEwweRxjP47E762bPyIko4Bx-eXrzhl/edit?usp=sharing) and found that if I deployed the authorization web app as "user running app" my copy of the library seemed to work fine from another Google Account.

Comment: @Jacobvdb drop me a line if you wanted to get this on Github so we can share what we find.

Comment: Copying it works fine indeed but I would like to get the authentication and authorization flow in the/a library, I'm just not sure if this is possible. About github I just thought it is not ready enough, but I'll put it up one of these days!

Comment: Hello again, I've since created my own library that was based on your code, amongst others: https://github.com/andrewroberts/GAS-TrelloApp. And I've used that in this add-on I've created - https://github.com/andrewroberts/GAS-TrelloSync

Comment: Nice! I'll give it a try one of these days!